# Adding bloom (glow) effect to shader (Unity game engine)

Tags: ios, opengl-es, shader, unity-game-engine

I am creating ***iOS app*** in [Unity game engine](http://unity3d.com).

I am trying to rewrite my ***shader*** so that the ***material***, witch using it, gave ***Bloom (Glow) effect*** (like a [Halo component](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-Halo.html)).

***An example*** of how it should look:

[image: Bloom (Glow) effect]

[image]

***I really searched answer in the internet but did not find anything for the worker or of suitable solution to my problem.***

My shader's ***code***:

```
Shader "Unlit"
{ 
    Properties
    {
        _MainTex("Base (RGB) Trans (A)", 2D) = "white" {}
        _Color("Main Color", Color) = (1, 1, 1, 1) 
    }
    SubShader
    {
        Tags{ "Queue" = "Transparent" "IgnoreProjector" = "True" "RenderType" = "Transparent" }
        LOD 100 
        Cull off
        ZWrite on 
        Blend SrcAlpha OneMinusSrcAlpha
        Pass 
        { 
            Lighting Off
            SetTexture[_MainTex]
            {
                constantColor[_Color]
                Combine texture * constant, texture * constant 
            }
        } 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Emission, and thus bloom amount comes fromthe value of the final pixel color value which should usually be in the HDR range. Try adding an emission property e.g. _Emission("Emmisive Strength", Range(0.01,3.0)) = 1.0. Then multiply your output by this property.

Comment: Can you show me how it should be done in my shader witch I add to question?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think it's that simple. You're currently using shader programs. To manipulate emission you'll need to re-write the shader as a surface shader instead of using programs. See here in the manual https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SL-SurfaceShaderExamples.html and do a find for "emission" there are many examples. That said I'm fairly new to it & would welcome other comments.

Comment: Are you using a Bloom Effect script?

Comment: Me need add to my shader (in question) bloom effect (like on screenshots).

Comment: You can use this example to learn how to create and update Unity Shaders. -> http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/simple-bloom-post-process-shader.103377/

Comment: Me don't need script for bloom image effect. Me need shader so that the material, witch using it, gave Bloom (Glow) effect (like a Halo component).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A shader program is just code used to draw triangles on the screen. Bloom effects are a completely different beast, [and are screen-space calculations that are done **after** the geometry is drawn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_(shader_effect)#Practical_implementation). You won't get a bloom effect just by modifying the object's shader.

Simply speaking, with a shader you can never draw "outside the lines", and here you need to alter pixels that are outside the object's reach. I'm sorry, but it's just not within the shader's capabilities.

Still, you can make it work by implementing [Image Effect](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/comp-ImageEffects.html) scripts, like unity's [built-in bloom effect](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-Bloom.html). Once the script is added to the camera, and the camera's HDR setting is activated, you can use a special shader that will result in a glow, but not before all that.

Once you have set up the effect correctly (and enable the HDR option on the camera), you can now use any shader that returns values greater than 1 in the pixel shader to generate a glow effect around the object. The shader you posted is a legacy shader program. Here's the updated code, with a Glow multiplier included:

```
Shader "Glow" {
    Properties {
        _MainTex ("Texture", 2D) = "white" {}
        _Color ("Color", Color) = (1,1,1,1)
        _Glow ("Intensity", Range(0, 3)) = 1
    }
    SubShader {
        Tags { "Queue" = "Transparent" "IgnoreProjector" = "True" "RenderType" = "Transparent" }
        LOD 100
        Cull Off
        ZWrite On
        Blend SrcAlpha OneMinusSrcAlpha

        Pass {
            CGPROGRAM
                #pragma vertex vert
                #pragma fragment frag

                sampler2D _MainTex;
                half4 _MainTex_ST;
                fixed4 _Color;
                half _Glow;

                struct vertIn {
                    float4 pos : POSITION;
                    half2 tex : TEXCOORD0;
                };

                struct v2f {
                    float4 pos : SV_POSITION;
                    half2 tex : TEXCOORD0;
                };

                v2f vert (vertIn v) {
                    v2f o;
                    o.pos = mul(UNITY_MATRIX_MVP, v.pos);
                    o.tex = v.tex * _MainTex_ST.xy + _MainTex_ST.zw;
                    return o;
                }

                fixed4 frag (v2f f) : SV_Target {
                    fixed4 col = tex2D(_MainTex, f.tex);
                    col *= _Color;
                    col *= _Glow;
                    return col;
                }
            ENDCG
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Unity selective per-object bloom - https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=XJ0tMHDrzDo. How I can create something like this with my shader?

Comment: By using a script on the camera like they use on the video. Look at the camera's inspector at 2:16

Comment: So can you show me how it should be done in my shader witch I add to question?

Comment: I simply added a multiplier to the color output. This will make the glow effect work if a Bloom script is used. Still, it's a bit strange that it's a transparent shader with ZWrite On, you might get unexpected results

Comment: Can I use bloom(glow) effect for only one object (like on video)?

Comment: Yes, you can. Here's how it works: the effect affects the camera, and whatever is drawn using this shader will be bloomed. If you only want one object with bloom, then only use this shader in one object

Comment: You decide my problem. Thanks you!